# What is the difference between Wal2json and Pgoutput?

Tags: postgresql, etl, logical-decoding

We are working on building a ETL pipeline. And I have come across these two plugins for postgres to capture the writes and deletes of the table.

Can someone please explain the differences between Wal2json and Pgoutput? What are the pros/cons and performance impact if there are any?

Basically I want to understand when to use among these two plugins in Postgres.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are for different purposes. `pgoutput` is for use with logical replication between PostgreSQL databases, `wal2json` is for getting a JSON representation of data modifications for use with third-party applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From this article: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/postgres-plugins.html
```
As of Debezium 0.10, the connector supports PostgreSQL 10+ logical replication streaming using pgoutput. This means that a logical decoding output plug-in is no longer necessary and changes can be emitted directly from the replication stream by the connector.
```
Which means for postgres supporting pgoutput, wal2json is no longer required. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sounds that way. But this is specific to Debezium, which you didn't mention in your question.